# OnMouseDown() execute only once

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following OnMouseDown() function:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("This turret is: " + thisTurret.ToString());
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (thisTurret != null)
    {
        buildManager.SelectTurret(thisTurret);
    }
```

which send to the following functions:

```
public void SelectTurret(GameObject turret)
{
    if(selectedTurret == turret)
    {
        Debug.Log("Selected turret is: " + selectedTurret.ToString());
        DeselectTurret(selectedTurret);
        return;
    }

    selectedTurret = turret;
    Debug.Log("Selected turret here is: " + selectedTurret.ToString());
    Debug.Log("Pasted turret here is: " + turret.ToString());
    if (oldSelectedTurret == null)
    {
        oldSelectedTurret = selectedTurret;
    }

    //Debug.Log("Selected turret is: " + selectedTurret.ToString());

    if (oldSelectedTurret != selectedTurret)
    {
        turretUI.Hide(oldSelectedTurret);

        //Debug.Log("Old in if Selected turret is: " + oldSelectedTurret.ToString());

        oldSelectedTurret = selectedTurret;
    }
    //Debug.Log("Current Selected turret is: " + selectedTurret.ToString());

    turretToBuild = null;

    turretUI.SetTarget(selectedTurret);
}

public void DeselectTurret(GameObject turret)
{
    if(turret != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Turret to deselect is: " + turret.ToString());
        turretUI.Hide(turret);
        selectedTurret = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Turret to deselect is null!");
    }
}
```

it should deselect the turret if clicked twice but instead it select the turret on first click and don't execute on second click

Comment: What does `Debug.Log("This turret is: " + thisTurret.ToString());` print on the second click?

Comment: nothing on second click

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems I was changing Layers but not all the children layers

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
    return;
}
```

Returns true on second click. It returns and does not execute other part of the code.

```
if (thisTurret != null)
{
    buildManager.SelectTurret(thisTurret);
}
```

Comment: I tried by commenting that if statement and it is doing the same thing